# Adding new field and populating with shapefile name

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a set of shapefiles that need a new field adding to them called "Policy_Ref". I then need to update this field with the shapefile name. However when I do, it uses the full title, including the .shp. However I do not want the .shp in the fields.
This is my code so far:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.workspace.env = r"teamGIS/shp"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Policy_Ref", "TEXT")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "Policy_Ref", "'" + fc + "'")
    arcpy.Merge_management(fcs, "new_shp")
```

How do I remove the .shp either before or after the code is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a Python rather than ArcPy question, so would be best researched at Stack Overflow.

However, you can try changing:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "Policy_Ref", "'" + fc + "'")
```

to:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "Policy_Ref", "'" + fc.replace(".shp","") + "'")
```

Comment: my personal favorite is fcName,fcExt = os.path.splitext(fc).. this way if there is no extension fcExt == '' but fcName always contains the name; this function also has tolerance for double extensions (eg. MyShp.tif.shp).

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use a describe and .baseName

```
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","","")
    for fc in fcs:
            desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
            print fc
            print desc.baseName
            ActualName = desc.baseName
```